# Let $T:V\to V$ over $\mathbb F$, $\dim V=n$, $\dim \operatorname{Im}T=1$. Prove that there's a scalar $a$ for all $v\in V$ such that $T^2(v)=aT(v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Let $T:V\to V$ over $\mathbb F$, $\dim V=n$, $\dim \operatorname{Im}T=1$. Prove that there's a scalar $a$ for all $v\in V$ such that $T^2(v)=aT(v)$.

The official solution is:

Because $\dim \operatorname{Im}T=1$ then there's a vector $w\neq 0$ such that $\operatorname{Im}T=\operatorname{span}\{w\}$. Then there's a scalar $k\in V$ such that $T(v)=kw$ and in particular there's $a\in V$ such that $T(w)=aw\quad \ast$.

Then:
$$
T^2(v)=T(kw)=kT(w)=kaw=akw=aT(v)
$$
**Why do we know** that there's a $w$ such that $T(w)=aw$ because every vector in the domain must have an image?

Comment: Yes that's correct. every element in the domain must have a image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, $$T(w)\in Im\, T = span\{w\}\Longrightarrow \exists a: T(w) = aw.$$
You can do this for any given $w\in V.$